# Moving an image in a Popup Modal not working, but in the main container

Tags: html, css, blazor, styling, webassembly

I'm working with a project in Blazor.

I'm using a component called "BlazorWheelZoom" (https://github.com/iso8859/BlazorWheelZoom)

This is my first page:

```
@page "/"
@page "/print"
@using Blazorise
@using LabelPrint.Shared
@using Linak.LabelPrint.Client.Shared.Components

<h3>Print</h3>


<div class="container-lg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div style="border: thin solid green; width: 510px; height: 510px; padding: 5px;">
                <WheelZoom Image="/Img/rotate0.png" width="500" height="500" />
        </div>
    </div>
.... and so on
```

For this HTML as you can see above, I get the following output:

[image]

The image refuses to move to the left, just as expected. If i zoom in a little bit I can move it a few pixels corresponding to the difference (the part of the image that you cannot see) and then it stops.

See the demo of the creator: https://blazorwheelzoom.azurewebsites.net

But when I add the exact same code to a popup Modal, I can keep moving it to the left.

[image]

I have the exact same HTML and CSS, so it must be something with the parent I guess. But I have tried to disable/enable stuff, but without luck. I just want the image to be prevented from moving "out of bounds" if you know what I mean.

This is the HTML in my Modal:

```
<Modal @ref="LabelPreview">
<ModalContent Centered="true" Size="ModalSize.Large">
    <ModalHeader>
        <ModalTitle>Show</ModalTitle>
        <CloseButton />
    </ModalHeader>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <Button @onclick="() => RotateImage(true)">
            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>
        </Button>
        <Button @onclick="() => RotateImage(false)">
            <i class="fas fa-undo"></i>
        </Button>
    </nav>
    <ModalBody>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="@($"{rotationClass} frame")">
                        <WheelZoom Image="@(rotate0)" width="500" height="500" />
                    </div>
                </div>
    </ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter>
        <Button Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@DownloadImage">Download</Button>
        <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@HidePreviewModal">OK</Button>
    </ModalFooter>
</ModalContent>
```

The Modal component I'm using is from Blazorise

This gotta be some CSS thing, but I'm about to give up. So hopefully some of you guys can help me.

Comment: can you host this code somewhere? so I can see the result in the browser and I can inspect the code.

Comment: I can't really share it without modifying it a lot, because this is a company project